# How to modify ConnectionString in app.config file from VB.NET windows application?

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, app-config, configurationmanager

I want to change the connection string of my application written in app.config file. I like to make changes in the connection string directly from my application.

My app.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationName.My.MySettings.ConnectionS"
      connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test"   value="/"  />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am able to make changes in **appSettings** with this code:

```
Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
config.AppSettings.Settings("Test").Value = "New value"
```

But I am not able to make changes in **connectionStrings** while debuging nither when the application is installed:

```
Dim config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
Dim connectionStringsSection = DirectCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings("ApplicationName.My.MySettings.ConnectionS").ConnectionString = "New connection string"
config.Save()
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

Answer (score 0):

To change it in code try something like the following;

```
Dim con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection1")
Dim con2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection2")
```

The 'connection1' and 'connection2' are the names of the connection strings within the app.config.

Comment: OK Ill take another look sorry!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim c As System.Configuration.Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection = DirectCast(c.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
section.ConnectionStrings("Services.My.MySettings.hassanConnectionString").ConnectionString = createCnxString()
c.Save()


Private Function createCnxString() As String
    Dim builder As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
    builder("Data Source") = datasourceTxt.Text
    builder("Integrated Security") = True
    builder("Initial Catalog") = "XXXX"
    builder("User ID") = usernameTxt.Text
    builder("Password") = passwordTxt.Text
    Return builder.ConnectionString
End Function
```